# String Concat Error with TouchDevelop

Tags: arrays, string, touchdevelop

I begun programming with TouchDevelop but I entered the error below.

```
action main ()      
var strings := collections → create string collection      
strings → set at(1, "I")      
strings → set at(2, "II")      
strings → set at(3, "III")      
strings → set at(4, "IV")      
strings → set at(5, "V")      
strings → set at(6, "VI")      
var x := math → random(6) + 1      
var s := strings → at(x)      
"The value of dice is " → concat(s) → post to wall # ERROR AT CONCAT(S)
```

Comment: And this has to do with Pascal.. ?

Comment: @Thomas, precisely nothing... :-) I've created a brand new [tag:touchdevelop] tag, but I'm afraid since it's just created, no one will notice the question. Do you have ideas which tags add to the question ? Weed, could you add some tags to your question to pay more attention, please ?

Comment: Sorry, Thomas. And thank you TLama. I added two tags 'string' and 'arrays'. I'm gonna wait for a moment.

Answer (score 0):

For the touchdevelop language you want to use the string concatenation characters, which is || . 
Your line would be:

```
"The value of dice is " || s → post to wall
```

The double-pipe character can be found in the third menu to the left next to the mathematical operators if you are using Windows Phone 7.